# How to grant permanent screenshot permissions for third-party apps in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: permissions, 22.04, screenshot

I use several apps that take screenshots like Upwork or Flameshot. But each time i should allow permission to take screenshot. How can I disable this feature or allow this permission forever? I use Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Software installed via snap or flatpak?

Comment: I don't remember about upwork, but flameshot installed via snap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution by myself. The reason of that behaviour was login using Wayland. But problem was solved by logout and login with Xorg. Use this link to see screenshots which will help https://itsfoss.com/switch-xorg-wayland/